# Substring in LWC Javascript

Tags: lightning-web-components, substring

How can we use substring in LWC.
I have a input tag, onclick of that input tag i am getting the event.target.name.
however i am not getting the substring output in LWC.
i do not get the last console.log.

```
onEmojiClick(event){
    alert(event.target.value);
    alert(event.target.name);
    var questionName =  event.target.name;
    alert(questionName);
    var questName = questionName.substring(0,questionName.indexof("-"));
    console.log('questName:-'+questName);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your code to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve? What do you mean by "substring output"?

Comment: @ChristianMenzinger i have added the code. Could you please check.

Comment: This is not specific to LWC but more of a JS question. The issue I see in your code is that you have a case sensitivity issue on index function. Remember JS is case sensitive, you should have it as - `questionName.indexOf("-")` (note the upper case O)

Comment: got it. thanks @JayantDas

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a JS question and not specific to LWC. Considering your all other input to the function is correct, you have a case sensitivity issue here on `indexOf` function as currently written. The current function is `indexOf` (notice UPPERCASE O).

The corrected line should be as below:

```
var questName = questionName.substring(0, questionName.indexOf("-")); // notice UPPERCASE O here
```